# Can we have all possible closed reasons in help page?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, documentation

Can we have all possible `closed_reasons` in help page and if possible, `closed_reason_id`, too?

For example

```
closed_reason_id=1, closed_reason="exact duplicate",
closed_reason_id=2, closed_reason="off-topic",
closed_reason_id=3, closed_reason="subjective and argumentative",
closed_reason_id=4, closed_reason="not a real question",
closed_reason_id=7, closed_reason="too localized",
closed_reason_id=104, closed_reason="belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com",
closed_reason_id=102, closed_reason="belongs on serverfault.com",
closed_reason_id=103, closed_reason="belongs on superuser.com",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closed reasons vary from site to site, and can be changed over the lifetime of the site.

Comment: Ok, so I need to store those closed reason texts as is in database. I was wondering there is something better.